# Convert XML data containing CDATA to JSON in Oracle

Tags: json, xml, oracle

I have a table test_tab, whose column is `tst_col` of `XMLTYPE`. while trying to convert `tst_col` of `XML` to `JSON`, I am successfully able to do so by using :

```
select xml2json(t.tst_col ).to_char() JSON_VAL FROM test_tab t;
```

But when `tst_col` contains `cdata` in it, I get an error.

> Whenever it encounters ]] it prematurely exit from an array.

Kindly help to process `XML` to `JSON`, when `XML` contains `CDATA`.

Comment: Where does the `xml2json` function come from? I can't seem to find any official documentation about it.

Comment: xml2json is a third party library, which i have included. For reference: http://www.armbruster-it.org/index.php/12-it/pl-sql/12-oracle-xml-and-json-goodies

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK XML2JSON is not a part of the Oracle database...

```
SQL> select xml2Json(xmltype('<Foo/>')) from dual;
select xml2Json(xmltype('<Foo/>')) from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "XML2JSON": invalid identifier

SQL>
```

However if I were creating such a function I would definitely consider a different name for it......

Comment: xml2json is a third party library, which i have included. For reference: http://www.armbruster-it.org/index.php/12-it/pl-sql/12-oracle-xml-and-json-goodies